# Why doesn't my sprite flip while using click and drag controls?

Tags: godot

I'm using the following code to control my player with click and drag:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
if Input.is_action_just_pressed("click"):
    selected = true

if selected:
    global_position = lerp(global_position, get_global_mouse_position(), 25*delta)
    var mouse_pos = get_global_mouse_position()
    if mouse_pos < global_position:
        $AnimatedSprite.set_flip_h(true)
        print("face left")
    elif mouse_pos > global_position:
        $AnimatedSprite.set_flip_h(false)
        print("face right")


func _input(event):
if event is InputEventMouseButton:
    if event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT and not event.pressed:
        selected = false
```

The player moves fine, but the sprite doesn't flip horizontally at all.  It always faces left (the original orientation).  The print commands however, seem to work as expected.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

I also have keyboard controls for the player, and the sprite flips as expected when I use:

```
$AnimatedSprite.set_flip_h(false)
$AnimatedSprite.set_flip_h(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your condition `if mouse_pos < global_position`, you are comparing two vectors.
However vectors contain both `x` and `y` members, so you need to adjust the code to compare those values separately, like this:

```
if mouse_pos.x < global_position.x:
   pass
else:
   pass
```